# MIPS Guessing Game with premade RNG

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

Alright so i'm using a premade PRNG (LFSR_Random) and calling it to get a random number, i'm then trying to put this number into a register so I can compare it to my guesses and get responses.

I'm having major issues calling this generator with JAL and getting it to where I want to store it, I think I have the correct logic in here but i've been getting non responses not even returning the strings just asking for ("Enter Number: ") again, so either the value in the register is completely off or its not comparing correctly.

And if need be I can upload the entire other set of functions(?) that utilize the PRNG for reference.
Just ask.

```
        .data
start:      .asciiz     "Guess Game(1-100)"
entnum:     .asciiz     "\n Enter number: "
toolow:     .asciiz     "\n Too Low"
toohigh:    .asciiz     "\n Too High"
correct:    .asciiz     "\n Correct"

        .text
        .globl main

main:
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, start                  #prints out the start string
        syscall

        li      $v0, 0                      #initiliaze register $v0

        move    $s1, $v0                        #move the random number into $s0
        jal     LFSR_Random                 #call the random number generator
                                            #LSFR_Random returns an upper 
                                            #32-bit unsigned number                 
                                            #in $v0
                                            #and a lower 32-bit number in $v1

        move    $s2, $s1                    #moves rn into s2

        remu    $t0, $s2, 100               #divides so i can get it between 1-99
        addi    $t0, $10, 1                 #now between 1-100

loop1:  
        li      $v0, 4
        la      $a0, entnum                 #print query
        syscall

        li      $v0, 5                      #enter query
        syscall

        blt     $v0, $t0, toolowc           #calls if the guess is too low
        bgt     $v0, $t0, toohighc          #calls if the guess is too high
        beq     $v0, $t0, correctc          #calls if the guess is correct
                                            #ending the loop and program.

toolowc:                        
        la      $a0, toolow                 #called from blt, prints response
        syscall
        j       loop1                       #resets to the loop

toohighc:
        la      $a0, toohigh                #called from bgt, prints response
        syscall
        j       loop1                       #resets to the loop

correctc:
        la      $a0, correct                #called from beq, prints response
        syscall

        j endcall                           #calls the ending call, ending the program
endcall:    
        li      $v0, 10
        syscall
########################
```

Comment: You have the `move $s1, $v0` and the `jal LFSR_Random` in the wrong order. You can't move the result of the function you haven't yet called.

Comment: I did that before, it didn't change much, i'm was getting the same output of the one i have right now.

Comment: Also I guess `addi $t0, $10, 1` should really be `addi $t0, $t0, 1` (`$10` is `$t2`). If it still doesn't work, use a debugger/simulator to single step your code.

Comment: Oh wow, that was a miscalculation on my part, everything works now, I really appreciate it.